# How to show menu only when on mobile or tablet view?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am building a website in HTML i want to create a menu that appears only when we are on mobile or tablet. I want to make a menu same like bootstrap mobile view menu but that menu must now be show when on desktop mode. As i already have a menu for that i just want to create a menu that shows up when we switch are on mobile or tablet view.

Comment: have you create different menu html for mobile and desktop menu ?

Comment: You could use bootstrap css class hidden-xs and visable-xs class etc http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: @UnmeshD i have create desktop sidebar menu but not mobile menu

Comment: so should i define the menu code inside it @wolfgang1983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use media queries add this in your css

```
#your-menu{
 display:none;
}
```

and at the end

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
 #your-menu{
 display:block;
}
}
```

read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre-defined class in bootstrap

```
hidden-sm
```

or `hidden-md`

for the menu bar.

Make a division around the menu bar for simplicity. Or just use the class in the menu unordered list.